# What can lymphocyte-produced antibodies do that 'innate' opsonins can't?

Tags: immunology, immune-system, antibody, antigen

I have a conceptual misunderstanding relating to immunology which I'd be grateful if anyone could help me clear up.

My A Level textbook says that at the start of an immune response, opsonins bind to antigens; these opsonins are "a type of antibody" that then increase the probability of the pathogen being phagocytosed by a macrophage or neutrophil.

Macrophage phagocytosis then leads to antigen presentation; the macrophage migrates to the lymph node and then the hope is that a lymphocyte with the specific receptor binds to the antigen on the macrophage APC. Clonal selection/expansion/differentiation follows, and the B plasma cells produce large amounts of antibody that are released into the blood.

But why is this necessary, **if the opsonins at the start of the process which tagged the pathogen for phagocytosis already exist in the body at the start of the response, before clonal selection?** What can the very specific lymphocyte-produced antibodies do that the more generic opsonins can't?